# Compute the radical of the ideals $(x-3)$, $((x+1)^3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ a commutative ring. I know that $\sqrt I=\{r\in R\mid \exists n: r^n\in I\}$, but I don't know how to compute $\sqrt I$ when $I$ is given.

> For example, how can I compute $\sqrt{(x-3)}$ and $\sqrt{((x+1)^3)}$?

By the way, what does $(x,y)^2$ mean ? (it's from primary decomposition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\sqrt{((x-a)^n)}=(x-a)$ is an immediate consequence of the definition. (Prove it by double inclusion)

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\sqrt{ (x-a)}$ on the right hand side? Since we don't know whatever $x$ is.

Comment: @user35359 : $x-a$ is an irreducible polynomial; so by euclid's lemma, if $x-a\mid P^n$ we have $x-a\mid P$.

Comment: I thought we're in an arbitrary Ring $R$, not necessarily polynomial ring.

Comment: $\sqrt{(x-a)}=(x-a)$. To see that start from $\forall I, I\subseteq\sqrt{I}$ and $(x-a)$ is a maximal ideal

Comment: ok, thanks, and what is $(x,y)^2$ ?

Comment: $I^2=I\cdot I$ is the ideal generated by products $x\cdot y, x\in I,y\in I$